# CodeBlocks error: "File cannot be saved" -Win10 64 Bits-

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm a C++ beginner, and I recently ran into an issue where absolutely no changes to a file could be saved.

I attempted uninstalling and reinstalling Code::Blocks into the same folder and uninstalling and reinstalling into a new folder, but the error keeps coming.

The only thing I've done differently since this used to work for me was install Anaconda's SciPy suite. This may be irrelevant of course. The associated questions I could find were primarily for exotic-looking build setups, whereas I'm simply trying to get started with basic programs.

Thanks in advance for any efforts to help!

Comment: Can you make a new simple project, Hello World will do, and compile it? If so your IDE and the backing compiler are most likely fine and you should take a closer look at your project settings.

Comment: It will allow me to run the default Hello world code that comes with a new project, but any changes to that code brings up the error. I selected a console application and ran the defaults in the next window. I tried making new projects but found the same error, even in code I had already made

Comment: Move out of code::blocks and see if you can successfully build from the command line.

Comment: My "guess" is the default directory is somewhere under `C:\Program Files x86\CodeBlocks\...` where you do not have write permission. Go set the default project directory to somewhere under `C:\Users\you` (where `you` is your windows user name) You could do `C:\Users\you\codeblocks`, but since I don't like typing, I just use `C:\Users\me\cb`

Answer (score 0):

> Create file and projets other than C directory . Do not create in C
>   They are protected folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run CodeBlock with Administrator privilege.

Comment: Bad idea. Better to ensure the project directory is in a proper location where you (as the windows user) have write permission. (further explaining in my comment below question -- before I noticed this was nearly 5 years old)

Comment: I think you are right! I counter this issue this morning so I try run as Administrator privilege. Seem work for me so I answer this. But true, you should create the project under the folder that you have write permission.